# Binding a Button to a RelayCommand within an ItemsControl container

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

In a WPF Application, I have a ViewModel that is exposing a collection of strings that I'm displaying as buttons through an ItemsControl container using a WrapPanel.  I haven't been able to bind the RelayCommand in my ViewModel to the buttons, however.

ViewModel (IncidentAddressesViewModel):

```
public IEnumerable<string> Addresses { get; set; }

public RelayCommand<string> ZoomToAddressCommand { get {
  if (this.zoomToAddressCommand == null) this.zoomToAddressComamnd = new RelayCommand<string>(this.ZoomToAddress);
  return this.zoomToAddressCommand;
}}

private void ZoomToAddress(string address) { MessageBox.Show (address); }
```

XAML:

```
<TabItem x:Name="IncidentAddressesTab">
  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Addresses}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
      <i:EventTrigger EventName="Command">
        <cmd:EventToCommand 
          Command="{Binding ZoomToAddressCommand}"
          CommandParameter="{Binding Text}"
         PassEventArgsToCommand="True" 
        />
      </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>

    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <Button Content="{Binding}" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  </ItemsControl>
</TabItem>
```

Xaml Code Behind that connects the DataContext

```
IncidentAddressesTab.DataContext = new IncidentAddressesViewModel();
```

The buttons are showing with the addresses.  When I set a breakpoint at the ZoomToAddressCommand, it does get hit once, but when I click the buttons, the ZoomToAddress method never gets invoked.

UPDATE to include binding details:
I am actually binding to the TabItem.  I have updated the XAML to include the additional tag and added the binding code in the XAML Code Behind.  I didn't know this was pertinent information or I would have added it in the beginning.. (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to change the structure a little bit,

I added a class:

```
public class IncidentAddress {
  public string Address { get; set; }

  private RelayCommand zoomCommand; 
  public RelayCommand ZoomCommand {
    get {
      if (zoomCommand == null)
        zoomCommand = new RelayCommand(Zoom);
      return zoomCommand;
    }
  }

  public void Zoom() {
    MessageBox.Show(Address);
  }
}
```

In my ViewModel,
this:

```
public IEnumerable<string> Addresses { get; set; }
```

changed to:

```
public IEnumerable<IncidentAddress> Addresses { get; set; }
```

and I removed the RelayCommand from the ViewModel and left it in the new class

The XAML ended up being this:

```
<TabItem x:Name="IncidentAddressesTab">
  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Addresses}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <Button Content="{Binding Address}" Command="{Binding ZoomCommand}" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  </ItemsControl>
</TabItem>
```

Comment: This is not the way of doing things, you are mixing your model and your viewmodel (where the commands should be). @Sheridan answer should be marked as the correct one...

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't work because you have tried to `Bind` the `Command` to the `ItemsControl` and not the `Button` controls. Have you tried this?:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Button Content="{Binding}" Command="{Binding DataContext.ZoomToAddressCommand, 
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type 
        YourViewNamespace:YourViewName}}}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

What we're attempting to do here is to `Bind` from the `DataTemplate` to the view model that I am assuming is set as the `DataContext` of the current view. Please replace "`YourViewNamespace:YourViewName`" with the actual names of your XML namespace and view.

UPDATE >>>

Ok, after looking at your code again, I can see that you are `Binding` to the `Addresses` collection simply using the property name. You say that the `DataContext` is set on the `ItemsControl`, so I'm assuming that by that you mean that your view model is set on the `ItemsControl.DataContext` property. If that is so, then we need to change our `Binding` to the `Command` like this:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Button Content="{Binding}" Command="{Binding DataContext.ZoomToAddressCommand, 
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

If your view model is not set on the `ItemsControl.DataContext` property, then this will not work and you will need to clearly tell me how you have connected your view model to your view. Before I just assumed that your view model was data bound to the `DataContext` of the containing view or `Window` as is normally done... maybe next time, you can provide this information in your question to make it easier for people to answer it?

UPDATE 2 >>>

Ok, you've updated the question with the essential `DataContext` information... perfect. Now I can answer your question properly without all the guessing... do you see how much easier this would have been if you had added that there in the first place? No matter... we're here now. Try this final example:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Button Content="{Binding}" Command="{Binding DataContext.ZoomToAddressCommand, 
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

To reiterate... this `RelativeSource Binding` will look up the visual tree until it finds a `TabItem` control. Then, it will look at the `DataContext` property of that control. Finally, it will look for a `ZoomToAddressCommand` property in the object (your view model) that is set as the `DataContext` of the `TabItem`... and there we are.

Comment: I removed the i:Interation.Triggers section underneath my ItemsControl and bound it the way you illustrated and the RelayCommand Property breakpoint does not hit now and the method does not get called

Comment: Also, the datacontext that is being set in the Xaml constructor is on the ItemsControl Parent (A TabItem).  Do I need to change the RelativeSource?

Comment: I actually am binding the datacontext one level higher.. I wish I had more time to program in WPF using MVVM, but this is kind of a one off project..

Comment: Dude... do you *want* help here? You're *still* not telling me how you have connected your view model... what does 'one level higher' mean? I simply can't answer your question until you provide that information... it's up to you.

Comment: I have added how I have connected the viewmodel in the original question.  The line of code is "IncidentAddressesTab.DataContext = new IncidentAddressesViewModel();" .  IncidentAddressesTab is the parent of the ItemsControl element (One level higher probably wasn't the best description there).  I most certainly do want help and am doing my best to provide you (and whomever else) with as much information as I can.

Comment: @Rob, did that fix your problem?

Comment: Nope... The breakpoint in the ZoomToAddressCommand property in my viewmodel is not being hit and the ZoomToAddress method is also not being called

Comment: I ended up solving it.  Instead of binding to a collection of strings, I created a new class that contained the Address and a relaycommand and bound it to that instead.  I'll post the entire solution in a few

Comment: I have been scouring the internet looking for an answer for a similar problem.  @Sheridan... you are awesome!  Great explanation, too!!